# Divergence of $\sum \frac{n-1}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Since $$\sum \frac{n-1}{n^2}=\sum\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
And $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges and $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, the series diverges if we can distribute the $\sum$ to each fractions. But I don't know how to justify that.

Also both Root test and Ratio test are inconclusive, I need to use the comparison test. But couldn't find the lower bound that diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the comparison test by comparing $\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac{n-1}{n^2}$ with $\frac12\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac1n$, since $\frac{n-1}{n^2}\ge\frac1{2n}$ for $n\ge 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the limit comparison test with $1/n$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also say that is this sum converges, thenfrom the fact that $∑1/n^2$ converges you get that $∑(1/n-1/n^2+1/n^2)=∑1/n$ converges, contradiction.